# Unsupported op in tensorflow when training model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

**Hello, I'm tring to train model with tensorflow2, but get following results:**

```
174 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Function invoked by the following node is not compilable: {{node __inference_train_s    tep_3739}} = __inference_train_step_3739[_XlaMustCompile=true, config_proto="\n\007\n\0...02\001\000", executor_type=""](dummy_input, dummy_input,     dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, ...).
175 Uncompilable nodes:
176 deep_fm/boolean_mask/Where: unsupported op: No registered 'Where' OpKernel for XLA_GPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node deep_fm/boolean_mas    k/Where}}
177         Stacktrace:
178                 Node: __inference_train_step_3739, function:
179                 Node: deep_fm/boolean_mask/Where, function: __inference_train_step_3739
180 
181 Adam/Adam/update/Unique: unsupported op: No registered 'Unique' OpKernel for XLA_GPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node Adam/Adam/update/Uniq    ue}}
182         Stacktrace:
183                 Node: __inference_train_step_3739, function:
184                 Node: Adam/Adam/update/Unique, function: __inference_train_step_3739
185 
186 Adam/Adam/update_1/Unique: unsupported op: No registered 'Unique' OpKernel for XLA_GPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node Adam/Adam/update_1/    Unique}}
187         Stacktrace:
188                 Node: __inference_train_step_3739, function:
189                 Node: Adam/Adam/update_1/Unique, function: __inference_train_step_3739
190  [Op:__inference_train_step_3739]
```

**Tensorflow version:**

**cuda:11.0, cudnn:8.0.5**

```
tensorflow                   2.4.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.4.0
tensorflow-io                0.32.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.32.0
termcolor                    1.1.0
```

How can I solve this? All opened dynamic library is successfully loaded.

At first some dynamic library is not successfully opened and I solve that problem, but still get this problem. What may cause this problem? Is it caused by wrong coding or tensorflow?